# WPF ListView Update

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have the following class: (it has an email field and password field but it's not releavent)

```
class Account {
    public string status {get;set;}
}
```

However upon updating the status field the actual ui doesn't change and doesn't call the property get method.

My XAML:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="accountListView" ItemsSource="{Binding AccountList}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding email}" Header="Email" Width="Auto"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding password}" Header="Password" Width="Auto" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding status}" Header="Status" Width="Auto"/>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

My UI Code:

```
public ObservableCollection<Account> AccountList {
    get; set;
}
```

On the constructor, i've set DataContext to this (MainWindow) and intialized the Observable Collection.

Already tried implementing NotifyProertyChanged and adding a private _string field like this:

```
public string status {
    get {
        return _status;
    }

    set {
        _status = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("status");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

// This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
// The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
// parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
private void NotifyPropertyChanged ( [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "" ) {
    if ( PropertyChanged != null ) {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and also tried setting the ItemsSource to make it requery the items.

How can I change my code to make it display the ObservableCollection in realtime? Right now it only shows the first status it gets while being added to the collection.

Setting ItemSource to null and then putting the collection back seems to work, but that's not good because any selections the user made will be gone.

Comment: How have you implemented NotifyPropertyChanged ? You have to specify which property changed `NotifyPropertyChanged("Status");`

Comment: Yeah. NotifyPropertyChanged needs name. You named it with little first letter. So `NotifyPropertyChanged("status");`

Comment: still does not call the property get method, and does not update the ui.

Comment: Double check you set the `DataContext` after the call to InitializeComponent in the constructor.

Comment: I did. @user2697817

Comment: You'll have to post more of your code, there's not enough to diagnose the problem. Perhaps show your xaml with the binding expressions and your `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation.

Comment: @user2697817, I believe what I added was it, I took it from another question

Comment: ok. This way we can see, that the `NotifyPropertyChanged` doesn't need argument truly. Can You show us the code, when the status is set? Or You want to use ListView as DataGrid?

Comment: DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding email,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" try this.It should work if binfding is correct.

Comment: @ntohl, The status is set in a different thread, and a ListView

Comment: @AbhinavSharma, did not work, does it mean the binding is not set up correctly? because it does read the first intial value correctly.

Comment: When is your collection created? Maybe its after the initial binding already happened, if this is the case you neew to do this NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(AccountList ); right after you create your collection

Comment: @adminSoftDK tried creating first and then setting the binding, and it didn't change anything

Comment: I know this may seem like a stupid question but does your `Account` class actually implement the interface? As in `class Acccount : INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Your *other thread* setting of `status` must be invoked on dispatcher thread I think. I would like to see the 2 codes where You set it.

Comment: @user2697817 not a stupid a question, it does not,let me try doing that

Comment: @Keddy1201 If that's the case that should definitely fix your problem. When you set the datacontext if the object implements that interface then WPF will attach an event-handler to the `PropertyChanged` event and react accordingly when the event is published.

Comment: It would not know the type has that event unless it's defined with that interface.

Comment: @user2697817, it worked, nice job on troubleshooting!
Submit an answer and i'll mark it as solved.

Comment: It's ok, no need now. As long as you're sorted.